# What's the negation of $ \ f: X\rightarrow Y\Rightarrow f(Ø)=Ø$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Definition 8. Let X and Y be sets. A function from X to Y is a triple (f, X, Y), where f is a relation from X to Y satisfying
>   (a) Dom(f) = X.
>   (b) If (x, y)$\in f$ and (x, z) $\in f$, then y=z.
>   We shall adhere to the custom of writing $f: X\space \rightarrow Y$ instead of $(f, X, Y)$ and $y=f(x)$ instead of $(x,\space y) \in f$.

I'm trying to find a negation of "Theorem 9 (a) Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$. Then $f(Ø)=Ø$"

Source: Set Theory, You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T. Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation would be:  there exist sets sets X and Y (could be any sets, even the empty sets) and a function $f:X\rightarrow Y $ such that $f(\emptyset) \ne \emptyset$.

Such a statement is ... nonsense as it would mean that there exists a $y \in f(\emptyset)$ such that $y= f (x); x \in \emptyset $.  This is utterly impossible as there is no possible $x \in \emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

So really, the statement is: For every map $f: X \to Y$, $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.

The negation of this is the statement that makes this false.  What makes this false?  If we can find just one map $f:X \to Y$ such that $f(\emptyset) \neq \emptyset$ (although there could be more than one such map, but for it to be false we need to find just one).

So the negation is: there exists a map $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(\emptyset) \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by negation? If $f: X \rightarrow Y$, then $f[\emptyset] = \emptyset$. This is a true statement.

Comment: I know that's true. Negation for example is [Negation of ($p\rightarrow q$) ]≡ ~($p\rightarrow q$)≡ ~($p∧$~$q$)≡ ~$p ∨q$